# All `ids` are always from the last object

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop

I want to add a delete option for a cookie of each `img` element inside `for-loop`. the problem is that  all `ids` are always from the last object.

what I've tried:

```
function listCookies() {
    var theCookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    var aString = '';
    for (var i = 1; i <= theCookies.length; i++) {
        (function (i) {
            if (theCookies[i - 1].indexOf("pauseCookie-") >= 0) {
                cookieArray = theCookies[i - 1].split("=");
                theCookie = $.trim(cookieArray[0]);
                cookieInfo = $.cookie($.trim(theCookie));
                cookieInfo = cookieInfo.split("^");

                ...

                htmlCode = "<div id='pauseDiv-" + theCookie + "'><a href='" + cookiePath + "'>" + cookieTitle + "</a> (" + pauseInfo + ") </div><br />";
                $("#cookiesContent").append(htmlCode);

                header = document.createElement('img');
                header.id = 'delImg' + theCookie;
                header.style = 'cursor:pointer';
                header.src = delImage;

                header.onclick = function () {
                    alert("#pauseDiv-" + header.id);
                    //$.removeCookie(theCookie,{path:'/'});
                    $("#pauseDiv-" + theCookie).html("<div class=\"pauseDivResponse\">Deleted</div>");
                }

                document.getElementById("pauseDiv-" + theCookie).appendChild(header);

            }
        })(i);
    }
}
listCookies();
```

alert("#pauseDiv-" + header.id); always prints the last id from all img elements I created.

Comment: Not a duplicate. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not directly related to closures, but is to do with your variable `header` being in the global scope. When you declare a new variable, you should use the `var` keyword, otherwise it is assumed to be a property of the global object (`window`).

If you enable strict mode (by adding `"use strict";` to the top of your code, or the top of the function), you will be told about these sorts of mistake.

To be clear, you need to change

```
header = document.createElement('img');
```

to

```
var header = document.createElement('img');
```

(and should do the same for *all* your variables)